# Setting HTML tag attribute before load

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I use cookies to remember a preference for the user. Basically, I have a left hand panel that can be collapsed or expanded using a button. When the user clicks it, I remember its state through the cookie.

Now I need to keep the initial load of the page in sync with what the cookie says, to prevent it from jerky behavior.

That is the class in `<body class="mini-navbar">`. This class either is there or not depending on the state.

I have all the methods to get and set a cookie.

My question is, how can I add/remove this class dynamically *before the page is loaded* based on the cookie?

Comment: Are you storing class name in the cookie so that when its empty you decide to remove the class from body else you add the class mentioned in cookie to body element?

Comment: No, it is just a binary cookie.

Comment: are you using asp.net MVC or WebForms?

Comment: It is asp.net MVC 5

Comment: You can check the answer that I have posted. Even though you have mentioned JavaScript in your question, I have also shown how you can use just C# to achieve your results. I have provided a JavaScript only solution too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either server-side code with Razor syntax or pure JavaScript to implement your scenario. Mixing JavaScript and server-side code for cookies can sometimes yield unexpected results, so go for a pure server-side approach  or a pure JavaScript approach.

The binary cookie in my example is called `bodyStyle` and it takes a value of 1 or 0. I am creating a persistent cookie that will expire 30 days from today and will be available/persisted across pages in your domain. Also, you can add some condition checking when creating the cookie or settings its value in both approaches according to your requirements.

The custom class that I am adding to body using cookie value is `miniNavBar`.

***Server-side approach***

The body tag will normally be there in a shared view and so add the Razor code below to shared view.

*C# Razor code to dynamically set body class using a binary cookie*

```
@{
    //set bodyStyle cookie based on some condition using a if statement as per your requirements
    Response.Cookies["bodyStyle"].Value = "1";
    Response.Cookies["bodyStyle"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2);
}

<body class="@(Response.Cookies["bodyStyle"].Value == "1" ? "miniNavBar" : "")">
```

***JavaScript approach***

The code below can go into any view that needs to have this logic, or add it to the shared layout view if you want to apply it to all views.

*JavaScript code to dynamically set body class using a binary cookie*

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //main cookie function that will contain your logic for creating the binary cookie
    function setBodyCookie() {
        //if perisistent cookie exists then do not create it         
        if (document.cookie.indexOf("bodyStyle=0") >= 0 || document.cookie.indexOf("bodyStyle=1") >= 0) {
               return;
        }

        //create body cookie if it does not exist
        //you can add an if statement here when creating a cookie based on your scenario
        var now = new Date();
        now.setTime(now.getTime() + 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);//expire this in 30 days from now
        document.cookie = "bodyStyle=1;expires=" + now.toUTCString() + ";path=/";
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        //set binary cookie according to your requirements
        setBodyCookie();

        //add class to body if binary cookie has a value of 1
        if (document.cookie.indexOf("bodyStyle=1") >= 0) {
            $("body").addClass("miniNavBar");
        }
    });


</script>
```

Another javascript solution if you want to avoid the flicker could be to place the document ready event code just after body tag in your markup and remove the original document ready event you were using, as shown below. You will notice that the document ready is not being used in code below.

```
<body class="expandedNavBar">
<script>
            //set binary cookie according to your requirements
            setBodyCookie();

            //add class to body if binary cookie has a value of 1
            if (document.cookie.indexOf("bodyStyle=1") >= 0) {
                //remove all classes that are already there or just remove the
                //the ones you like to
                $("body").removeClass();
               //add your class now
                $("body").addClass("miniNavBar");
            }
</script>
```

Another alternate is that you could use the `.hide` class to avoid flicker as body class is changed in document ready event. This is shown in sample code below.

```
<style>
   .hide{ visibility:hidden}
</style>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
            //set binary cookie according to your requirements
            setBodyCookie();

            //add class to body if binary cookie has a value of 1
            if (document.cookie.indexOf("bodyStyle=1") >= 0) {
                $("body").removeClass("hide");//remove the hide class
                $("body").addClass("miniNavBar");
            }
        });
</script>
<body class="hide">
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Sunil for the sample code. I am using the client side approach and that is what I already got but the problem I see is that , `$(document).ready` doesn't seem to happen first. What happens first is the rendering of whatever the `<body>` says. So if the tag by default (i.e in the code) is `<body>` then the panel expands first then `$(document).ready` will instruct to collapse (based on the value of the cookie). Or vice versa. This causes that blink or jerky motion. If the body tag was being updated before rendering through the `$(document).ready` then I think it would fix it.

Comment: If you used server side code that I have provided then this problem would be solved. If you want to use client-side approach, then always have a class called `.hide{ visibility:hidden} ` added to body markup. Then in document ready event, you can remove this hide class after the binary cookie logic using `$("body").removeClass("hide")`

Comment: Also as an alternate to my last comment, place the Javascript that is in document ready inside a script tag just after the body tag in your markup  so it executes before body is rendered. And remove the document ready event from your page.

Comment: thank you so much. That is very good idea. I used the hide class as you suggested, now it looks like the whole page reloads rather than that annoying panel. This is much much better. I mark your answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

if you use javascript to set cookie you can place javascript in  section and set class ( i use jquery for exmaple)

```
if(document.cookie // cookie name)
{ 
    $("body").addClass('mini-navbar'); 
}
```

or if you use php or something else you can write:

```
<body `<?php echo $COOKIE['bodyClass']; ?> `>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am not so sure where to add this. I had already tried the above `$("body").addClass('mini-navbar'); ` in document.ready, or I even tried to use onload event on the `<body>` but still not luck.

Comment: how you set cookie?

Comment: Using jscript `document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";`. I guess if I could figure out how to do something similar to your php example in mvc5 razor that could solve the problem.